# how do I calculate bi-directional distance without using for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have a list with `n` numbers. I need to calculate the BD distance of each member of the list to all other members and sum all distances for each number and then select the number that has the lowest sum distance to all other members. I used two `for` loops for this, but it is time-consuming. is it a way to calculate this distance without using `for` loop? as you know the distance between `i` and `j` is the same but we calculate it two times in each loop. I have the distance of all points to each other in a big NumPy array. here we have some part of points in each cluster.

```
for itr2 in range(K):
            tmp_cl=clusters[itr2+1]
            if len(tmp_cl)>1:
                BD_cent=np.zeros((len(tmp_cl),1))
                for itr3 in range(len(tmp_cl)):
                    sumv=0
                    for itr5 in range(len(tmp_cl)):
                        BD_R=bd_rate(rate,tmp_cl[itr3,:],rate,tmp_cl[itr5,:])
                        BD_R=(BD_R-min_BDR)/(max_BDR-min_BDR)
                        BD_Q=bd_PSNR(rate,tmp_cl[itr3,:],rate,tmp_cl[itr5,:])
                        BD_Q=(BD_Q-min_BDQ)/(max_BDQ-min_BDQ)
                        value=(wr*BD_R+wq*BD_Q)
                        if value!=np.NINF:
                            sumv+=(value)
                        else:
                            sumv+=1000#for curves which have not overlap with others
                    BD_cent[itr3]=sumv/len(tmp_cl)
                
                new_centroid_index=np.argmin(BD_cent)
                centroid[itr2]=clusters[itr2+1][new_centroid_index]
```

Comment: It's really an O(N*N) problem.  You can shortcut it a little bit -- if the result for a row ever exceeds the current minimum, then you can skip the rest of that row.

Comment: What is the definition of bidirectional distance? Is the difference in position or in value?

Comment: What is `cluster`, `bd_rate`, `rate`, `min_BDR`, `max_BDR`, `bd_PSNR`, `wr`, `wq`, `centroid`

Comment: Please make a MRE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . It is not possible to generically vectorize functions efficiently (`np.vectorize` just hide the loop which does not help)

Comment: This is not true? NumPy for loops are way more efficient than python loops. I suspect OP just means if they can do this more efficiently, not necessarily without loops. (X/Y problem)

Comment: Can you provide your numpy arrays / reproducible example?

Comment: It can be done in O(N log(N)), and just to sort the numbers. The remaining calculations are close to O(N)

Comment: I am trying to implement KMeans clustering with my distance instead of Euclidean distance. the problem is in updating the centroids. I try to find the point in a cluster which has the lowest summation of distance from all other points in the cluster and select it as a new centroid. bd_rate and bd_psnr are functions that calculate the distance. cluster is a list of all clusters I have in the problem and centroid is a list of all cluster centroids that I have. other parameters are used for normalization or as a weight.

Comment: I have a NumPy array that contains the distance of each point to all other points. an array with size nxn

Answer (score 0):

This should be `O(N log(N))` for the sort, and `O(N)` to find the minimum.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array([11, 32, 71, 167, 217, 308, 366, 411, 449])

x = np.sort(data)
position = np.arange(len(x))

# distances between neighboring points
xdiff = np.diff(x, prepend=0, append=0)

# From here, most calculations are unnecessary, because 
# the minimum point depends on local conditions, and
# can be obtained from the change in position and xdiff

# delta distance = (distance between neighboring points)*position
xAccumLeftToRight = np.cumsum(xdiff[:-1]*position)
xAccumRightToLeft = np.cumsum(xdiff[::-1][:-1]*position)[::-1]

# Sum of distances to the left and to the right
sumDist = xAccumLeftToRight+xAccumRightToLeft

# Finding minimum. Can be speeded up with an log n search
# because it descends monotonically to the center
# (and then ascends monotonically)
indexMin = np.argmin(sumDist)

print(f"minimum distance at {x[indexMin]}")

print(xdiff)
print(xAccumLeftToRight)
print(xAccumRightToLeft)
print(sumDist)

plt.plot(x, sumDist)
plt.scatter(x[indexMin], sumDist[indexMin])
plt.show()
```

[image]